# How I am able to omit the parameter object sender in Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with a Web Form in ASP.NET and I want to understand that why can I omit the parameter in override Event Handler?

This is Event :

```
public event EventHandler Init;
```

This is Delegate to Hold Data(with two parameters) :

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Event Handler goes like :

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
      i++;
      this.Load += Page_Load;
}
```

Adding parameter is not allowed in above method(handler) but at the same time we are restricted to pass parameter in below case

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    Response.Write(i);
}
```

Note : I have disabled my Auto Event Wire-Up attribute in Directive.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are looking for. You want to redefined the Init event?

Comment: @CodeNotFound, I am looking for some reason why we can omit the parameter, is it something pertaining to AutoEventWireUp? Also, I think we can't refine this event as it is using EventHandler delegate?

Comment: Again I don't understand :) You are looking to be able to define a event handler without respecting the signature of the delegate ? You want to write something like `protected void Page_Load(EventArgs e)` instead of the complete signature  `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not subscribing to Init event. AutoEventWireUp make sure Page_Init method is called when Init Event is fired.

As you have disable it, then you have to manually hook up the method like this

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Init += new EventHandler(OnInit); 
    base.OnPreInit(); // make sure you call this
}
```

Reason you will not get compile time error is because there are two types of EventHandler delegate

```
EventHandler(object,EvnetArgs)
EvnetHandler(EventArgs)
```

Comment: This is delayed response but consider it for conversation. I believe if "AutoEventWireUp = true" this will ensure that only mention two events from page life cycle, PreInit, Load will call their respective handler in xxx.aspx.cs file Page_Init and Page_Load event. Second, why we need to call base.OnXXEvent(e); every time like in Page life cycle.

Comment: Last, best I know about EventHandler(object,EvnetArgs) is this way URL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx whereas other seems like some special delegate https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, is that what you point in last statement?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `Page_Load` really is an event handler whereas `OnInit` is a method that is defined in the base class and raises the `Init` event. So in the case of your `OnInit` method, you are overriding the method and not defining an event handler.

If you want to create an event handler for the `Init` event, you would also have to create a method with the following signature:

```
protected void Page_Init(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

This only works if `AutoEventWireUp` is set to true. Otherwise, you need to register event handlers in your ASPX page or the codebehind file. As the `Init` event is raised very in the page lifecycle, the event handler needs to be registered at the beginning of the request. In the special case of `Init` it is very common to override `OnInit` instead of defining an event handler. Important to note though, if you override `OnInit` (or one of the other `On*` methods) you should always call the base version in order to allow for the ASP.NET framework to do its stuff:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    // initialization code
}
```

Comment: I believe this is incase of Auto Event Wire up is true...OP has mentioned it is false